# Python - A keyboard command to stop infinite loop?

Tags: python, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana, infinite-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I handle a KeyboardInterrupt in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606942/why-cant-i-handle-a-keyboardinterrupt-in-python)

I was playing around with some Python code and created an infinite loop:

```
y = 0
x = -4

itersLeft = x
while(itersLeft<0):
    y = y + x
    itersLeft = itersLeft - 1
    print "y = ",y, "itersLeft = ", itersLeft

print y
```

Is there a keyboard shortcut that would allow me to stop the looping - allowing me to fix the loop and then restart it?

I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and didn't have any luck.  If it helps I'm using a Windows 7 environment.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

---

I should have also mentioned that I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and attempted to run the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command within that.  It doesn't work there - but trying it within the regular console works fine.  I'm assuming it must be because of the Aptana environment.

Comment: That should do it. What did you use to run it?

Comment: Seeing that you are using Aptana Studio 3, is it at least 3.03? http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-1469 What happened when you killed it with task manager? Have you tried ctrl+z?

Comment: press the red stop button on the eclipseIDE

Comment: Why the hell is this marked as a duplicate? That's just plain dumb, excluding cursing. The so-called "original" is about catching *KeyboardInterrupt* errors.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is what you need. If it didn't work, hit it harder. :-) Of course, you can also just close the shell window.

Edit: You didn't mention the circumstances. As a last resort, you could write a batch file that contains `taskkill /im python.exe`, and put it on your desktop, Start menu, etc. and run it when you need to kill a runaway script.  Of course, it will kill *all* Python processes, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks Kindall.  I should also have mentioned that I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and attempted to use the Ctrl-C command there.  It works fine in the regular terminal window, but not within Aptana.  I actually had to restart Aptana in order to stop the loop.

Comment: @Phillip: Don't know about Aptana, but most IDE's have a "Stop" or "Stop and Restart" button for console apps.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help - I was just hoping the keyboard shortcut would work within Aptana.

Comment: what if you executed the python script from rc.local?  :(

Comment: I've got nothing but an anecdotal "hunch" but I feel runaway printing responds more snappily to `<C-c>` when the `-u` command line flag (for unbuffering stdout/err) is set.  Eg. `python -u my-loop-script.py`.

Comment: Does Ctrl-C throw an exception that would mean it wouldn't work if it's in a try block?

Comment: On linux/osx you could use `pkill -f mynastyscript.py` — so you will only kill your script and not everything else. You don't have to include the extension if the name is unique enough since `-f` will match by any substring in the full command line.