# Safe way to exit an infinite loop within a Thread Pool for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am using **Python3** modules:

- `requests` for **HTTP GET** calls to a few Particle Photons which are set up as simple **HTTP Servers**
- As a client I am using the Raspberry Pi (which is also an Access Point) as a **HTTP Client** which uses `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` for making **HTTP GET** resquests to the above mentioned photons

The polling routine is as follows:

```
def pollURL(url_of_photon):
    """
    pollURL: Obtain the IP Address and create a URL for HTTP GET Request
    @param: url_of_photon: IP address of the Photon connected to A.P.
    """
    create_request = 'http://' + url_of_photon + ':80'
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1) # poll every 100ms
            response = requests.get(create_request)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                # if success then dump the data into a temp dump file
                with open('temp_data_dump', 'a+') as jFile:
                    json.dump(response.json(), jFile)
            else:
               # Currently just break
               break
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            print('KeyboardInterrupt detected ', e)
            break
```

The `url_of_photon` values are simple **IPv4 Addresses** obtained from the `dnsmasq.leases` file available on the Pi.

the `main()` function:

```
def main():
    # obtain the IP and MAC addresses from the Lease file
    IP_addresses = []
    MAC_addresses = []
    with open('/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases', 'r') as leases_file:
        # split lines and words to obtain the useful stuff.
        for lines in leases_file:
            fields = lines.strip().split()
            # use logging in future
            print('Photon with MAC: %s has IP address: %s' %(fields[1],fields[2]))
            IP_addresses.append(fields[2])
            MAC_addresses.append(fields[1])

            # Create Thread Pool
            pool = ThreadPool(len(IP_addresses))
            results = pool.map(pollURL, IP_addresses)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Problem

The program runs well however when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> the program does not terminate. Upon digging I found that the way to do so is using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

How do I use this in my `pollURL` function for a safe way to exit the program, i.e. perform `poll.join()` so no leftover processes are left?

**notes**:

the `KeyboardInterrupt` is never recognized with the function. Hence I am facing trouble trying to detect <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>.

Comment: Probably you have the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543534/why-is-keyboardinterrupt-not-working-in-python)

Comment: Actually [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774853/exit-multiprocesses-gracefully-in-python3?rq=1) is the nearest possible thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pollURL` is executed in another thread. In Python, signals are handled only in the main thread. Therefore, SIGINT will raise the KeyboardInterrupt only in the main thread.

From the [signal documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/signal.html#signals-and-threads):

> Signals and threads
>
> Python signal handlers are always executed in the main Python thread, even if the signal was received in another thread. This means that signals can’t be used as a means of inter-thread communication. You can use the synchronization primitives from the threading module instead.
>
> Besides, only the main thread is allowed to set a new signal handler.

You can implement your solution in the following way (pseudocode).

```
event = threading.Event()

def looping_function( ... ):
    while event.is_set():
        do_your_stuff()

def main():
    try:
        event.set()
        pool = ThreadPool()
        pool.map( ... )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        event.clear()
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Comment: Do you think `pool.terminate()` should be within the `except` block?

Comment: In general, threads cannot be terminated. Therefore, calling `pool.terminate()` would be redundant. What you need to make sure is that nothing blocks your workers indefinitely or they will never get to evaluate `event.is_set()`. Make sure your requests have a timeout set and it should be enough.